# Consecutive dates (up to 5) count as single occurrence if it is for same exception code and exclude Saturday and Sundays

Tags: sql-server-2016

I have a problem on SQL Server.
While counting for occurrences, system shall consider consecutive dates (up to 5) count as single occurrence if it is for same exception code and exclude Saturday and Sundays while considering consecutive days.

I did try with CTE below is the output I am getting.

```
DROP TABLE

IF EXISTS #Occurrence
    CREATE TABLE #Occurrence (
        EmpId INT
        ,DATE DATE
        ,Day VARCHAR(100)
        ,ExceptionCode VARCHAR(100)
        )

INSERT INTO #Occurrence (
    EmpId
    ,DATE
    ,Day
    ,ExceptionCode
    )
SELECT 1
    ,'2020-12-01'
    ,'Tuesday'
    ,'Sick Leave'

UNION ALL

SELECT 1
    ,'2020-12-02'
    ,'Wednesday'
    ,'Sick Leave'

UNION ALL

SELECT 1
    ,'2020-12-03'
    ,'Thursday'
    ,'Sick Leave'

UNION ALL

SELECT 1
    ,'2020-12-04'
    ,'Friday'
    ,'Sick Leave'

UNION ALL

SELECT 1
    ,'2020-12-05'
    ,'Saturday'
    ,'Sick Leave'

UNION ALL

SELECT 1
    ,'2020-12-06'
    ,'Sunday'
    ,'Sick Leave'

UNION ALL

SELECT 1
    ,'2020-12-07'
    ,'Monday'
    ,'Sick Leave'

UNION ALL

SELECT 1
    ,'2020-12-08'
    ,'Tuesday'
    ,'Sick Leave'

UNION ALL

SELECT 1
    ,'2020-12-09'
    ,'Wednesday'
    ,'Casual Leave'

UNION ALL

SELECT 1
    ,'2020-12-10'
    ,'Thursday'
    ,'Sick Leave'

UNION ALL

SELECT 1
    ,'2020-12-11'
    ,'Friday'
    ,'Sick Leave'

UNION ALL

SELECT 1
    ,'2020-12-12'
    ,'Saturday'
    ,'Sick Leave'

UNION ALL

SELECT 1
    ,'2020-12-13'
    ,'Sunday'
    ,'Sick Leave'

UNION ALL

SELECT 1
    ,'2020-12-14'
    ,'Monday'
    ,'Sick Leave'

UNION ALL

SELECT 1
    ,'2020-12-15'
    ,'Tuesday'
    ,'Sick Leave'

UNION ALL

SELECT 1
    ,'2020-12-16'
    ,'Wednesday'
    ,'Casual Leave'

UNION ALL

SELECT 1
    ,'2020-12-17'
    ,'Thursday'
    ,'Sick Leave'

UNION ALL

SELECT 1
    ,'2020-12-18'
    ,'Friday'
    ,'Sick Leave'

UNION ALL

SELECT 1
    ,'2020-12-19'
    ,'Saturday'
    ,'Sick Leave'

UNION ALL

SELECT 1
    ,'2020-12-20'
    ,'Sunday'
    ,'Sick Leave'

UNION ALL

SELECT 1
    ,'2020-12-21'
    ,'Monday'
    ,'Sick Leave'

UNION ALL

SELECT 1
    ,'2020-12-22'
    ,'Tuesday'
    ,'Sick Leave'

UNION ALL

SELECT 1
    ,'2020-12-23'
    ,'Wednesday'
    ,'Sick Leave'

UNION ALL

SELECT 1
    ,'2020-12-24'
    ,'Thursday'
    ,'Casual Leave'

UNION ALL

SELECT 1
    ,'2020-12-25'
    ,'Friday'
    ,'Sick Leave'

UNION ALL

SELECT 1
    ,'2020-12-26'
    ,'Saturday'
    ,'Sick Leave'

UNION ALL

SELECT 1
    ,'2020-12-27'
    ,'Sunday'
    ,'Sick Leave'

UNION ALL

SELECT 1
    ,'2020-12-28'
    ,'Monday'
    ,'Sick Leave'

UNION ALL

SELECT 1
    ,'2020-12-29'
    ,'Tuesday'
    ,'Casual Leave'

UNION ALL

SELECT 1
    ,'2020-12-30'
    ,'Wednesday'
    ,'Sick Leave'

UNION ALL

SELECT 1
    ,'2020-12-31'
    ,'Thursday'
    ,'Sick Leave';

WITH CTE
AS (
    SELECT EmpId
        ,DATE
        ,DateName(DW, DATE) DayName
        ,ExceptionCode
    FROM #Occurrence WITH (NOLOCK)
    )
SELECT CTE.*
    ,CASE 
        WHEN NEWCount = 1
            THEN 1
        ELSE 0
        END AS Occr_Count
FROM CTE
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT EmpID
        ,ExceptionCode
        ,MIN(DATE) AS DATE
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY EmpID
            ,ExceptionCode
            ,MIN(DATE) ORDER BY EmpID
                ,ExceptionCode
                ,MIN(DATE)
            ) AS NEWCount
    FROM (
        SELECT EmpID
            ,DATE
            ,ExceptionCode
            ,Datediff(D, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                    ORDER BY EmpID
                        ,DATE ASC
                    ), DATE) AS Diff
        FROM CTE
        ) AS X
    GROUP BY EmpID
        ,ExceptionCode
        ,Diff
    ) AS Derived ON CTE.EmpID = Derived.EmpID
    AND CTE.ExceptionCode = Derived.ExceptionCode
    AND CAST(CTE.DATE AS DATE) = CAST(Derived.DATE AS DATE)
ORDER BY CTE.EmpID
    ,CTE.DATE
```

But below is the output I am expecting:

[image]

Comment: What is the point of `NOLOCK` on a local temp table? You might as well do `TABLOCK`

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT
    EmpId,
    Date,
    DateName(DW, DATE) DayName,
    ExceptionCode,
    CASE WHEN PrevDate IS NOT NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END Occr_Count
FROM (
    SELECT *,
        CASE WHEN DATENAME(DW, Date) NOT IN ('Sunday','Saturday') THEN
            LAG(Date) OVER (PARTITION BY
                EmpID,
                ExceptionCode,
                CASE WHEN DATENAME(DW, Date) IN ('Sunday','Saturday') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
                ORDER BY Date)
        END PrevDate
    FROM #Occurrence
    WHERE 
) t

ORDER BY CTE.EmpID, CTE.DATE;
```

There are more efficient methods to do this, but this will suffice unless you have a perf issue.

Comment: I did try with above approach but it didn't work out as not getting as expected output shown in expected excel screenshot.

Comment: I did try with above approach but it didn't work out as not getting expected output shown in expected excel screenshot.

Comment: What are you getting?

Comment: 1 2020-12-01 Tuesday Sick Leave 1
1 2020-12-02 Wednesday Sick Leave 0
1 2020-12-03 Thursday Sick Leave 0
1 2020-12-04 Friday Sick Leave 0
1 2020-12-05 Saturday Sick Leave NULL
1 2020-12-06 Sunday Sick Leave NULL
1 2020-12-07 Monday Sick Leave 0
1 2020-12-08 Tuesday Sick Leave 0
1 2020-12-09 Wednesday Casual Leave 1
1 2020-12-10 Thursday Sick Leave 0
1 2020-12-11 Friday Sick Leave 0
1 2020-12-12 Saturday Sick Leave NULL
1 2020-12-13 Sunday Sick Leave NULL
1 2020-12-14 Monday Sick Leave 0
1 2020-12-15 Tuesday Sick Leave 0
1 2020-12-16 Wednesday Casual Leave 0 ..etc